# How to select a range of Excel rows based on content in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 10k+ lines Excel file, that is structured as follows: (in column A): "Name of City is:" followed by a few rows starting with
"contribution from..." followed by 
lines of no interest... followed by 
"END OF CASE"... and repeat.
I need to extract the rows starting with "Name of City" and the "contribution from" rows that follows the Name of City, and paste each group of rows in a separate sheet.  Can you help?  Thanks eternally.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your* code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know , I understand your problem.

```
Sub transData()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    vDB = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If Left(vDB(i, 1), 4) = "Name" Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        End If
            vR(n) = vR(n) & " " & vDB(i, 1)
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```

Or,

```
Sub transData()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    vDB = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If Left(vDB(i, 1), 4) = "Name" Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        End If
            If Left(vDB(i, 1), 4) = "Name" Or Left(vDB(i, 1), 12) = "contribution" Then
                vR(n) = vR(n) & " " & vDB(i, 1)
            End If
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```